# proportionally enlarging shrinking (ctrl +-) the entire web page pure css

Tags: css

I want that my page enlarge or vica verca with ctrl + or - proportionally and i have no clue how to do that. Any help would be very good. http://jsfiddle.net/3Lhe7/14/  Adding this css just that i could link my demo at jsfiddle.

```
body {
max-width: 1000px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 body {
   zoom: 2;  /* or any zoom amount you want */
}
```

Comment: it just makes the menu bar bigger

Comment: @RokasStankaitis , try hitting CTRL + and see what happens , the background image doesn't change , this will do the same

Comment: when i hit ctrl + the text at the bottom goes onto the menu bar, it doesnt zoom to height, if you know what i mean

Comment: thats because that little window in jsFiddle isn't big enough , the browser window will do the same if you keep zooming in - everything will overlap

Comment: Im always testing in my browser, not jsfiddle, it still overlaps, but it shouldn't do that, that text should be at the bottom of the page even if i zoom it to infinity and beyond :)

Comment: it worked, i converted all of my units to em (from % and px), and it now shrinks and enlarges proportionally